# Easy way to render a 3d model using Kinect SDK

Tags: kinect, 3d-rendering

i'm getting used to Kinect SDK and the WPF applications (totally newbie in both of those).

My application now get normal video, depth generated video and depth and color value for each pixel, done with kinect sdk in a little time :) Now i need to render every point i got in a 3d space. For every point i already have X Y Z coordinates, i just need an easy way to render it.

Here what i already tried:

- Using D3DImage WPF component and DirectX, result: don't have time to
  master directX C++ coding
- Using D3DImage WPF component and SlimDX, result: can't find any
  useful documentation on SlimDX OR how to write the render output in
  the D3DImage component
- Using WPF and XNA, result: Can't import XNA in visual studio 2012,
  can't made it work in 2010. Found several examples, none of those
  builds or compile
- Using Winforms and XNA, result: works, but pretty hard to convert
  code from KinectSDK
- Using WPF and MonoGame, result: No example or documentation on how to
  implement Monogame inside WPF, only a post blog on how to implement XNA
  on WPF in a not so efficent way

Now.. i really have NO IDEA how to do it.. so i'm asking for some help here. A little example on how to draw points in a 3D ambient could be a good starting point, if mouse interaction is possible for rotating the model it can be totally Perfect :)

Any idea? :)

Comment: Have you looked at the Kinect For Windows Developer Toolkit examples?  There is an example of how to manipulate an avatar.

Comment: If you would consider C++ I would recommend the Point Cloud Library ([visualization example](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php#pcl-visualizer)). For C# check also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053212/point-cloud-viewer-in-net).

Comment: i loved the PointCloudLibrary and i wasted lot of time to configure it, i got some nice results compiling examples but got stuck while trying to merge Qt and PCL in the same application. After 2 days of pain i decided to go back to my old WPF approach and managed to include a directX interface in WPF application using sharpDX, now i just need to draw the point cloud using sharpDX!

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem some time ago. The best solution is to use Winforms and XNA. There is no good way to combine XNA and WPF and that is not going to change anytime soon. Are you trying to create a window or a full screen applications? Are you struggling with anything in particular when using WinForms?

Comment: after some struggling on this topic i found my way, not an easy way tough :(
Using SharpDX i can easily add a drawing component on my WPF application just following the WPFHost example on documentation, now i'm trying to learn how to use pixel shaders to make a point cloud :D